# Inserting HTML into a text area using WysiHat and a custom rte button

Tags: rte

I am trying to create a button which inserts custom HTML into a rich text area.

So far I have added the button, and triggered an alert:

```
return "
    WysiHat.addButton('insert_slide_show', {
        label:         EE.rte.insert_slide_show.label,
        handler: function(editor)
        {
            alert("hello"); 
        }
    });
";
```

I have tried inner html:

```
this.innerHTML("<p>something</p>");
```

and jQuery html:

```
this.html("<p>something</p>")
```

both of which seem to submit the page, i suspect this is due to an error with the html.

I also looked threw the documents on this and still have no clue, any help would be appreciated.

So in summery I'm looking to insert custom html into a rich text area on a button click, using a custom rte button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a little bit of rummaging around on the EE site and some intuition I found this:

```
this.Commands.insertHTML();
```